# PHP is Displaying Code for no reason

Tags: php, html, apache, echo

I have a PHP file function and at a certain point in the code it starts to echo everything to the screen, yet the code still works.

Initially I thought that an echo wasn't closed off properly, but it seems to be, even when I comment out the echo, it still prints it to the screen.

Below is a sample of the code around where the code starts to be displayed.

```
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');         //Details to connect to the specific database and table, password is left blank
    mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn);                     //mysql command to pick the specific database and runs the connection 
            //Clear data from Table
    mysql_query ("TRUNCATE TABLE imported_orders2");         //Runs mysql query to delete all data in the specified table
        //Informs User
    //echo "<br>Uploaded File: <br>";  //Tells the user the name of the file they have uploaded
    //echo "<br>Uploaded File: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";  //Tells the user the name of the file they have uploaded

        //Move uploaded file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);       //When the file is first uploaded it is saved in a temporary location and only exists while the php is running, this moves the file to a specific folder permanently
        //Delete first Line
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YMoC.png) is a link to a screenshot of what is displayed I have highlighted where everything seems to mess up.

Comment: @Stanyer That's a PHP function, not a custom function.

Comment: @DenizZoeteman - braindead moment, of course it is -.-

Comment: The output is not coming from the code you provided.

Comment: As @Joren said, from the code you've posted - there's no output.

Comment: Please post the whole code from your example screenshot

Comment: @Joren: He's obviously commented out the echo's, as he described too.

Comment: @Deniz: He also says it happens after commenting it, so something's not right.

Comment: looks like this: `?> ... echo $_FILE...`

Comment: Could it be `mysql_query ("TRUNCATE TABLE imported_orders2");` having a space there: `mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE imported_orders2");`? Don't think it would, but maybe.

Comment: This question needs more detail in order for it to be answered, namely the code that is being output.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP file has proper PHP Open tag and Close tag.

If it is, check your PHP.INI file has **short open tag is on**, If it is Off change your PHP open tag  to  or change your PHP.INI file short open tag is On.

Answer (score 0):

I think you closed php tag before `$_FILES["File"]["Name"]` used in your code.

You can try replacing

```
$_FILES["File"]["Name"]
```

by

```
<?php echo $_FILES["File"]["Name"]; ?>
```

It will show you name of file.